# Issue in integrating google translate in react app . Trying to override some changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, multilingual, google-translate

```html
// LanguageSwitcher.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function LanguageSwitcher() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Define the callback function for the Google Translate API
    window.googleTranslateElementInit = function () {
      new window.google.translate.TranslateElement(
        {
          pageLanguage: 'en', // Default language (English)
          autoDisplay: false, // Do not display the widget automatically
          includedLanguages: 'es,fr,de,en',
          
        },
        'google_translate_element'
      );
    };

    // Load the Google Translate widget
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src =
      'https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit';
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="google_translate_element">

        
    </div>
  );
}

export default LanguageSwitcher;
```

```html
.goog-te-banner-frame{
  display:none !important;
  margin-top: -20px  ;
  }

  
  .goog-logo-link{
    display:none !important;
   }
 .goog-te-gadget{
  color:transparent!important;
  }
  .VIpgJd-ZVi9od-l4eHX-hSRGPd{
    display:none !important;
  } 

  .goog-te-combo option[value="fr"] {
    /* background: url('../src/Images/usa.png') no-repeat; */
    padding-left: 20px; /* Adjust as needed to give space for flag */
  }

  .goog-te-gadget .goog-te-combo {
    margin: 7px 0 0 5 !important;
    width: 150px !important;
    position: relative;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
```

> I'm trying to, add multilingual functionality in my web app in react. I need to add some images like flags inside the Options of the select component inside the component from google script, I tried to override some of the CSS of the google component. but still, I cannot acheieve my goal, I would appreciate if anyone can tell how to integrate the google translate Api inside a custom select component using libraries like MUI , Antd , etc. ...

I tried to override some of the CSS of the google component and tried to add images inside it , it was not successful.

Comment: Could you please provide the package you are using and the code for your trial?

Comment: @MohammedNagdy I'm not using any specific package .Just trying to append the script  in a div , im exporting this component and using it in my header component